# How to add more than one image to application using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, blob

I have an application which allows to add an image to a product but I don't know how to refactor it that there will be possibility to add many images to one product.

This is model:

```
  @Entity   
  public class ProductEntity {

   @Lob
   private byte[] image;

   public String getImageBase64() {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(this.image);
}
```

This is Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
@Secured(ROLE_ADMIN)
public String saveProduct(ProductDTO productDTO, @RequestParam("image2") MultipartFile[] files) {
    try {
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            InputStream is = files[0].getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(buffer);
            productDTO.setImage(buffer);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    productService.addProduct(productDTO);
    return "redirect:/product/list";
}
```

Comment: Create One to Many relationship. ProductEntity and MediaEntity (whatever you wanna name it).